# Find probability of specific PIN code

Tags: probability-theory

Credit card PIN codes are $4$-digit number that is chosen at random (all combinations allowed). What is the probability you are assigned a PIN code that is divisible by $5$ and contains the number $45$ (as two consecutive digits)?

So there is $10000$ combinations possible.
We need numbers:
$45\#0$
$45\#5$
$\#450$
$\#455$
$\#\#45$

where $\#$ is $0-9$.

Sum of this numbers $10+10+10+10+100 = 140$, so $140$ is amount of numbers that satisfies the condition, and the probability is $140/10000=0.014$. But it's a wrong answer. I don't understand why.

Comment: You double-counted 4545

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks! Shame on me it was so simple ...

Comment: You also double-wrote “number”.

Comment: @kimchilover: I'm pretty sure that 4523 is not divisible by 5.